# Google plus share link response issue

Tags: social-networking, google-plus

I am using below code to share link on google plus.

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onPlusStart = function(x) {
        console.log('ops', x)
      }

      window.onPlusDone = function(x) {
        console.log('opd', x)
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>     
      <div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-href="http://test.com"
        data-onstartinteraction="onPlusStart"
       data-onendinteraction="onPlusDone">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

ISSUE : Right now i am getting response four times in console log for onPlusDone at the time of successfully share(response 1 : before login window, response 2 : after close login window, response 3 : after close login window, response 4 : after share successfully).

But i need response only one after successfully share.